# Check if object of any array exist in an another array, if not exists then push onto another array , or else remove it from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a checkbox ui react web app, where in, on check we dispatch items array with a object in it, and on uncheck also we dispatch items array with object in it. So I need to add this logic - Check if object of any array exist in an another array, if not exists then push onto another array , or else remove it from another array

```js
let items1 = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }];
let items2 = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "d" }, { name: "e" }];

const commonItems = items1.filter((x) => items2.some((y) => y.name === x.name));

if (!commonItems) {
    items1.push(...items2);
} else {
    items1 = items1.filter((x) => items2.some((y) => y.name !== x.name));
}

console.log(items1);
console.log(items2);
```

Check if object of any array exist in an another array, if not exists then push onto another array , or else remove it from another array,
Is this code corect for above logic?

Comment: I edited this to be an interactive snippet that logs `items1` and `items2` after running. Note I changed `const` to `let` because your script is updating `items1`, and you can't do that with a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues. 1) `commonItems` is always a truth value because filter returns empty array when no results, so always going to else block 2) Else block filter is not correct. (updated here to use !some)

```js
let items1 = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }];
let items2 = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "d" }, { name: "e" }];

const commonItems = items1.filter((x) => items2.some((y) => y.name === x.name));

console.log(commonItems)
if (commonItems.length < 1) {
    items1.push(...items2);
} else {
    items1 = items1.filter((x) => !items2.some((y) => y.name === x.name));
}

console.log(items1);
console.log(items2);
```